# Поиск пиков в аккумуляторном массиве Хафа

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, информатика

Необходимо реализовать функцию преобразования Хафа (Hough Transform) для поиска прямых на изображении на python. В реализации функции заполнения аккумуляторного массива проблем не возникло. Однако на этапе выделения пиков, соответствующих прямым возникли проблемы. Были варианты реализации через отсечение значений меньших порога. При таком подходе терялись короткие линии на изображении. Поиск максимума в некоторой eps-окрестности  тоже не дал должного результата.
Наткнулся на одну идею выделения пиков:

[image: Анализ пространства Хафа]

Вопрос в том, как это реализовать наиболее оптимальным способом или может быть уже есть похожая реализую в какой-либо библиотеке.

Comment: Так у вас opencv в тагах, в ней же есть поиск прямых Хафом

Comment: @MBo, да, есть, но в opencv преобразование Хафа завязано на пороговой фильтрации пиков. А от этого я как раз хочу уйти